# count number object in binary picture on

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need some help , the task is to [count these black shapes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ20g.png)

The algorithm for segmentation is as follows:

```
val=1
for x=1:no. of column
  for y=1:no. of rows
    if image(x,y)= 0    /* if a shape point */
       segment(image, val, x, y) ;
val=val+1 ;

function segment(image, val, x, y)
    image(x,y)=val ;
    for i=-1:1
      for j=-1:1
        if image(x+i,y+j)=0    /* if a shape point */
             segment(image,value,x+i,y+j)
end function
/*  After the call to the function, all the pixels of the shape are marked by the values val, and by this way it is separated from the other shapes and background. These points are not tested again (they are no longer zero)
```

My code make me an error , the code is :

```
global image
val=1
image=imread('cell.bmp'); %load picture
%imshow(image)%show image
%size(image) %view the length and with op the picture

for x=1:no. of column
  for y=1:no. of rows
    if image(x,y)= 0    /* if a shape point */
       segment(image, val, x, y) ;
val=val+1 ;

function segment(image, val, x, y)
    image(x,y)=val ;
    for i=-1:1
      for j=-1:1
        if image(x+i,y+j)=0    /* if a shape point */
             segment(image,value,x+i,y+j)
end function
```

Thanks

Comment: don't you think it would make sense to share the error you're facing?please read [ask]

Comment: why not use `regionprops` or `bwlabel` ?

Comment: `if image(x,y)= 0` This is probably your error. `=` is an assignment. The comparison operator is `==`.

Comment: I don't think `end function` is valid MATLAB syntax.

Comment: Invert your image, then use the marked duplicate.

Comment: Hey ,I new to matlab and try to use in bwlabel func but its working.can somewone write me the code withe bwlabel.

Comment: I tried "==" its sayes Unexpected MATLAB operator.

Comment: The duplicate implements `bwlabel`

Comment: Can you write me the code with bwlabel ?

Comment: Are you not understanding what I just said? The duplicate **implements `bwlabel`**.  It has already been coded for you.  There is a yellow bar at the top of this page that has a link.  Click on that link with your mouse using the left mouse button.

Comment: Oo thanks I dont see it probably because I on my phone